# What's different Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape and Uri.EscapeUriString

Tags: c#

The service received the string from Uri.EscapeUriString and Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape are difference, then I use Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape to handle url is ok.

What's different between Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape and Uri.EscapeUriString in c#?

Comment: Why would you ever be considering using [`escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/9yzah1fh%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)? "Deprecated ... The **escape** function should not be used to encode Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI). Use **encodeURI** and **encodeURIComponent** functions instead."

Comment: thanks you answer at first. In my case, I need generate Uri in the backend, so I choose one of them to escape Uri.

Comment: But the documentation for one of them says "don't use this function" - so why are you still considering using that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Uri.EscapeUriString` is available to use in C# out of the box, it can not convert all the characters exactly the same way as JavaScript escape function does.

For example let's say the original string is: "Some String's /Hello".

`Uri.EscapeUriString("Some String's /Hello")`

**output:** 
"Some%20String's%20/Hello"

`Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape("Some String's /Hello")`

**output:** 
"Some%20String%27s%20/Hello"

Note how the Uri.EscapeUriString did not escape the `'`.

That being said, lets look at a more extreme example. Suppose we have this string "& / \ # , + ( ) $ ~ % .. ' " : * ? < > { }". Lets see what escaping this with both methods give us.

```
Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape("& / \\ # , + ( ) $ ~ % .. ' \" : * ? < > { }")
```

**output:** "%26%20/%20%5C%20%23%20%2C%20+%20%28%20%29%20%24%20%7E%20%25%20..%20%27%20%22%20%3A%20*%20%3F%20%3C%20%3E%20%7B%20%7D"

`Uri.EscapeUriString("& / \\ # , + ( ) $ ~ % .. ' \" : * ? < > { }")`

**output:** "&%20/%20%5C%20#%20,%20+%20(%20)%20$%20~%20%25%20..%20'%20%22%20:%20*%20?%20%3C%20%3E%20%7B%20%7D"

Notice that `Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape` escaped all characters except `+`, `/`, `*` and `.`, even those that are valid in a uri. For example the `?` and `&` where escaped even though they are valid in a query string.

So it all depends on where and when you wish to escape your URI and what type of URI you are creating/escaping.

Comment: Much appreciate, it's very clear and easy understanding. I do generate Uri in back-end, and the service does use Js to un-escape Uri, so that's why It doesn't work when I used Uri.EscapeUriString to escape Uri.